# How to make responsive sidebar with Bootstrap without filling the whole screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the code of [bootstrap-side-navbar](https://github.com/samrayner/bootstrap-side-navbar) and building on top of [this demo](http://www.samrayner.com/bootstrap-side-navbar/). That's pretty much what I need but I want it not to fill the whole screen on desktop.

The problem is that when I add a `max-width` to `.container-fluid` the sidebar's column and the content's overlap, see the screenshot:

[image]

Whats a good, responsive, solution for this?

Comment: can you post working example

Comment: It's the one in the demo linked, but here you go anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/3r5jvpb1/

Comment: so why d you want to add  max-width to .container-fluid, still it looks great

Answer (score 1):

Replace container-fluid with container and add following css

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
    float: right;
}
```

I am calculating width by`css calc` property but still you have to write media query to handle the layout in different screens.